# Format date javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente cadena:

```
var fecha = "10-ene-2000";
```

Me gustaria formatearlo de la siguiente manera pero que siga siendo un string:

```
var result = "2000-01-10 00:00:00"
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo automáticamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para ello primero tendrás que recoger la fecha en formato (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ). Después convertirlo a string. De donde viene fecha? Cómo lo estás recogiendo?

No te sirve de nada formatear de "10-ene-2000" (string) a "2000-01-10 00:00:00" (string), ya que un string no contiene la hora/minutos/segundos.

Te dejo un enlace a W3C de paso: [Date Formats](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp)

Por que entiendo que querrás que la hora/minutos/segundos sean correctos verdad?

EDITO: Edito según comentario:

```
//Convertir el string a fecha para poder modificarlo
Date.parse(fecha);
//Poner el formato que quieres
dateFormat(fecha, "yyyy, mm, dd h:MM:ss");
//Volver a convertirlo a string
fecha.toString();
```

Comment: no es necesario la hora ni minutos, ya que solo me llega la fecha, lo unico que tengo que hacer es agregarle el 00:00:00

Comment: @sirdaiz Ya lo he editado, te ha servido al final?

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, al final no tuve que hacer esto pero tiene buena pinta el codigo

Answer (score 1):

Si el tema de no tener precisión con la hora, los minutos y los segundos te da igual (es decir, que se genere un string con 00:00:00) creo que esta solución te puede valer.

Lo primero es mapear los strings de los meses como números (igual hay alguna función que lo haga, pero como no la conozco yo te recomiendo este método que es más flexible).

```
function convertirFecha(fecha){
    //Objeto javascript que vamos a utilizar como tabla hash para
    //La conversion de los meses a su representacion numerica

    let conversorMeses = {
        'ene' : '01',
        'feb' : '02',
        (...),
        'dic' : '12'
    };

    //Obtenemos el dia mes y año de la fecha original
    //Tal y como has puesto:
    //paramFecha[0] -> dia
    //paramFecha[1] -> mes
    //paramFecha[2] -> año

    let paramFecha = fecha.split("-");

    //Una vez tenemos los datos montamos el string resultante 
    let fechaRes = paramFecha[2] + "-" + conversorMeses[paramFecha[1]] + "-" + paramFecha[0] + " 00:00:00";

    return fechaRes;

}
```

Comment: lo que queria evitar era escribir más codigo, sino algo con funciones de formato que pueda reutilizar